# php - how to extract a particular word from url removing question mark

Tags: php, .htaccess

```
HTTP://localhost/website/?search=hello+world
```

This is the URL and I just want to extract **hello world** from it

Right now i am using this code:

```
if(isset($_GET['q'])) {
   $url = $_GET['q'];
   $x = rtrim($url,'/');
   $x = explode('/',$url);
   print_r($x);
   echo($url);
}
```

But this does not show anything after the question mark. Is there anything wrong with this code or the `.htaccess` file.

I have also included the `.htaccess` file with code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-+/]+)$ index.php?q=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-+/]+)/$ index.php?q=$1
```

Comment: .htaccess rules not matches `?search=hello+world` then $_GET['q'] will be empty

Answer (score 1):

Use php inbuilt function parse_url()

http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php

```
$url = 'http://username:password@hostname/path?arg=value#anchor';

print_r(parse_url($url));
```

results

```
Array
(
   [scheme] => http
   [host] => hostname
   [user] => username
   [pass] => password
   [path] => /path
   [query] => arg=value
   [fragment] => anchor
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [**parse_url**](http://php.net/parse_url) and [**parse_str**](http://php.net/parse_str) function:

```
$str = "first=value&arr[]=foo+bar&arr[]=baz"; 
parse_str($str); 
echo $first; // value 
echo $arr[0]; // foo bar 
echo $arr[1]; // baz
```

Comment: To format your code blocks, paste the code in the  `edit` field, select it and click the Code button (the one saying `{ }`) above the edit field. I've edited the answer, but feel free to change it as your liking.

Answer (score 1):

I think [parse_ur()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) is your friend!

```
$url = 'HTTP://localhost/website/?search=hello+world';
$parsed = parse_url($url);
echo $parsed['query'] ; // search=hello+world
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `htaccess` rule is wrong..

It must be

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-+/]+)$ index.php?search=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-+/]+)/$ index.php?search=$1
```

and the code should be

```
if(isset($_GET['search'])) {
$url = $_GET['search'];
$x = rtrim($url,'/');
$x = explode('/',$url);
print_r($x);
echo($url);
```